# Accessing a single element of a parameter-pack-typed tuple using a dynamic index

Tags: c++

[I can use an index sequence or `std::apply` with a fold expression to apply some operation to every element in a tuple of vectors typed with a variadic template.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68184914/11628630)

I want to implement a method `setValueAt` that only sets the value at a row of a single vector in a tuple using a dynamic index.

This is my current solution:

```
    #include <tuple>
    #include <memory>
    #include <vector>
    
    using std::tuple;
    
    template <typename... Args>
    class Foo
    {
        protected:
            tuple<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Args>>...> data;
    
        public:
            Foo(size_t size) {
                std::apply([=] (auto&...arr) {((arr = (std::make_shared<std::vector<Args>>(size))), ...);}, data);
            };

        private:

            template <size_t idx>
            void setter(size_t tupleIdx, size_t row, std::tuple<Args...>& val)
            {
                if (tupleIdx != idx) {return;}
                (*std::get<idx>(data))[row] = std::get<idx>(val);
            };
    
            template<size_t...Is>
            void _setValueAt_(size_t tupleIdx, size_t row, std::tuple<Args...>& val, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
                (setter<Is>(tupleIdx, row, val), ...);
            };
    
        public:
    
            void setValueAt(size_t tupleIdx, size_t row, std::tuple<Args...>& val)
            { _setValueAt_(tupleIdx, row, val, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>()); };
    };

int main() {
    Foo<int, double, int> f(5);
    std::tuple<int, double, int> tup(1,1.1, 1);
    f.setValueAt(1, 1, tup);
    return 0;
}
```

This solution compares the dynamic index against each element of a static index sequence, allowing the equivalent static index to be used for the actual indexing. I'd love a more efficient and/or more elegant way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You might create array and subscribe:

```
template <typename... Args>
class Foo
{
// ...
private:

    template<size_t...Is>
    void _setValueAt_(size_t tupleIdx,
                     size_t row,
                     std::tuple<Args...>& val,
                     std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        using Funcs = void (*)(Foo<Args...>&, std::tuple<Args...>&, std::size_t);
        Funcs funcs [] = { [](Foo<Args...>& self,
                              std::tuple<Args...>& val,
                              std::size_t row)
            { (*std::get<Is>(self.data))[row] = std::get<Is>(val); } ...};
        
        funcs[tupleIdx](*this, val, row);
    }

public:

    void setValueAt(size_t tupleIdx, size_t row, std::tuple<Args...>& val)
    {
        _setValueAt_(tupleIdx, row, val, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5394b59b6f73603e)